# how to divide the array-list and make slices and pass in web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have arraylist of ids contains 1000 of records and this will be passed to WCF service as parameter and I get response of 1000 records. Now my requirement is to break the 1000 into 10 chunks and call the service 10 times. How can I do this in c# asp.net client?

Example: suppose I have 150 ids to be passed, in this case 100 ids in one function call and 50 should be in second call. Like this if I have 270 ids then 100, 100 and 70 three chunks to be created and three call to be made for the service.

The code I am using right now is pasted below and in this code i am passing all the ids ata a time

```
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();

if (parsedData.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in parsedData)
                    {
                        myArrayList.Add(new Identifier() { Id = item.First() });
                    }
                }

ServiceReference.CustomerProfileServiceClient clientObj = new ServiceReference.CustomerProfileServiceClient();

var responseObj = clientObj.GetProfiles( myArrayList.ToArray(typeof(Identifier)) as Identifier[]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Not really an answer to your problem, but ArrayList's are generally seen as deprecated now.  You would probably be better with a strongly typed List<T>

Comment: Have you reconsidered retagging this question? asp.net and wcf has no relevance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
int iCount = 0;

if (parsedData.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in parsedData)
                    {
                        myArrayList.Add(new Identifier() { Id = item.First() });
                        iCount++;
                        if (iCount % 10 == 0)
                        { 
                              ServiceReference.CustomerProfileServiceClient clientObj = new ServiceReference.CustomerProfileServiceClient();
                              var responseObj = clientObj.GetProfiles( myArrayList.ToArray(typeof(Identifier)) as Identifier[]);
                              myArrayList.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Darren Young; use typed lists. Further, Use Linq. For inspiration Look at this: [Split List into Sublists with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq).